# Update view based on drop down list selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if my question header isn't really clear as I don't know how to summarize it well.

So my scenario here is to provide a list of `checkbox` selections for the user to select. This list of selections will vary based on the `dropdownlist` selection. So far, this is my implementation but I don't really know how to manipulate the list of selections from the view using jquery:

**View:**

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.moduleID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.moduleID, new SelectList(Model.ModuleList, "value", "text"),
     "- Please select a Module -", new { @onchange = "PopulateObj()", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ObjectiveList.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ObjectiveList[i].isAssigned)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ObjectiveList[i].text)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ObjectiveList[i].text)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

**Script:**

```
    <script>
        function PopulateObj() {
            var moduleID = $('#moduleID').val();
            //implementation to change Model.ObjectiveList
        }
    </script>
```

Basically, I would like to get the `model.moduleID` from the `dropdownlist` selection and then populate the `Model.ObjectiveList` with data based on the `model.moduleID`. How should I do this?

Comment: So what is the Issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use Ajax :

```
<script>
        function PopulateObj() {
            var _moduleID = $('#moduleID').val();

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                    data: {moduleID: moduleID},
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#DivResultat").empty();
                        $("#DivResultat").html(response);
                    }
                });

        }
</script>
```

in your Action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(string moduleID)
{
    var model = new myModel();
    model.ObjectiveList = //get your list
    return PartialView("path_of_partialView", model)
}
```

partial view :

```
<table class="table">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ObjectiveList.Count(); i++)
    {
<tr>
      <td>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ObjectiveList[i].isAssigned)
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ObjectiveList[i].text)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ObjectiveList[i].text)
      </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Main View :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.moduleID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.moduleID, new SelectList(Model.ModuleList, "value", "text"),
     "- Please select a Module -", new { @onchange = "PopulateObj()", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="DivResultat">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Mostafa for your feedback..but I would like to ask if implementing partial view includes the data together when I post the form?

Comment: yes. the data in the partial view will be included in the form